# 404 Errors Trying to Install build-essential

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I'm using the Linux Subsystem for Windows 10, using ubuntu 18.04

I ran `sudo apt-get update` first. Then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Then whenever I run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` I get around 25 404 errors similar to the one below. Am I missing a step?

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
...

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-x86-64-E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Ensure that your Windows system has a working internet connection, including IPv6 connectivity. You do seem to be using the correct IPv6 address. Next, open a terminal and try `traceroute 2001:67c:1562::19`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I uninstalled Ubuntu 18.04 that I acquired from the Microsoft Store. And then installed the generic ubuntu one without a version. Did everything else the same with no issues.